# .NET REGEX Get Integer ONLY , exclude WHOLE DECIMAL

Tags: .net, regex

I have a sample string `'((1/1000)*2375.50)'`

i want to get the 1 and 1000 which is an INT

I tried this REGEX expression:

- `-?\d+(\.\d+)?` => this matches `1, 1000, and 2375.50`
- `-?\d+(?!(\.|\d+))` = > this matches `1, 1000, and 50`
- `-?\d+(?!\.\d+&(?![.]+[0-9]))?` => `1, 1000, 2375, and 50`

What expression do I have to use to match (`1 and 1000`)?

Comment: Are all your input string in the format `((x/y)*z)`?

Comment: @Chrono: No, that was just a sample string. Any string would do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically you need to match sequences of digits that are not preceded or followed by a decimal point or another digit? Why not try just that?

```
[TestCase("'((1/1000)*2375.50)'", new string[] { "1", "1000" })]
[TestCase("1", new string[] { "1" })]
[TestCase("1 2", new string[] { "1", "2" })]
[TestCase("123 345", new string[] { "123", "345" })]
[TestCase("123 3.5 345", new string[] { "123", "345" })]
[TestCase("123 3. 345", new string[] { "123", "345" })]
[TestCase("123 .5 345", new string[] { "123", "345" })]
[TestCase(".5-1", new string[] { "-1" })]
[TestCase("0.5-1", new string[] { "-1" })]
[TestCase("3.-1", new string[] { "-1" })]
public void Regex(string input, string[] expected)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?<![.\d])|-)\d+(?![.\d])");
    Assert.That(regex.Matches(input)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.ToString())
            .ToArray(),
        Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

Seems to work.

Comment: YOUR PATTERN WORKS LIKE A CHARM, WORKS ON ANY STRING

Comment: @Bienvenido, well, first of all, it's no reason to SCREAM. And another thing, as Kobi noted, I totally forgot about the minus sign. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
(?<!\.)-?\b\d+\b(?!\.)
```

[Working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5c.)-%3f%5cb%5cd%2b%5cb(%3f!%5c.)&i=((1%2f1000)*2375.50)%0d%0a12%2b13.44%2b44.00%2b41)

- `(?<!\.)` - No period before the number.
- `-?` - Optional minus sign
- `\b\d+\b` - The number. Wrapped in a word boundary, so it will not be possible to match withing another number (for example, do not match `1234` in `12345.6`). This will not match `2` in `2pi`.
- `(?!\.)` - No period after the number.

Comment: Better than mine because you have though of the minus sign and integers possibly being a part of an identifier.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov - Thanks! The minus is part of the question (all patterns begin with `-?`). The `2pi` thing might be a bug on my pattern, we may want to match these integers.

Comment: Ah, I missed the minus in the question. Fixed that now. By the way, you have a bug with that minus here. In a string like `"3.-1"`, you won't match `"-1"`.

Comment: @Sergey - Maybe. Maybe `3.` is a valid number. Maybe `3.0-1` should match just `1`, not `-1` (as opposed to `3.0*-1`). There's not enough information here for a spec `:P`

Answer (score 1):

[Try this:](http://rextester.com/ZVPE48556)

```
    string pattern = @"\(\(([\d]+)\/([\d]+)\)\*";
    string input = @"'((1/1000)*2375.50)'";


  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Groups[2].Value);

  }
```

Comment: Tahnks for the answer. I Tried it,but  the pattern matches `((1/1000)*` i only want 1 and 1000

Comment: you can try now